# Python - Regex matching not only what I want

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, numbers, scientific-notation

I've made this Regex which should match positive and negative integers (3, -7), floats (-6.3, 3.14), scientific notations (-17e3, 10e-10, 53e7) and "incomplete" numbers (.1, -.7e+10):

`([+-]?(([0-9])*(\.[0-9]*)?)([eE][+-]?[0-9]*)?)`

It also matches strings like `"e10"`, `"e"` and `"10e"` and empty strings which I don't want.

How can I fix the Regex without breaking the whole thing?

Comment: Can you provide a rule I could use to tell which strings you don't want?  Or even better, some unspoken requirement that needs to be added to your regex?

Comment: Try `([+-]?([0-9]+\.?|[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+))([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?)`

Comment: You should use alternatives in the regexp to match the different possibilities. Otherwise it's hard to express that two optional parts of the pattern cannot both be omitted.

Comment: Try ([+-]?([0-9][0-9]*\.?|[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+))([eE][+-]?[0-9][0-9]*)?) – 
(Similar to Michael Butscher 's sol'n but w/o the '+')